# How to redirect mail from d1.com to d2.com using DNS?

Tags: email, redirect, dns, record

I have 2 domains, let's call them d1.com and d2.com. 
I want mails sent to anyone@d1.com to end up in a mailserver at d2.com.
I want to use DNS to accomplish this and first tried the following to get it to work:

- On d1.com I set a MX record "@   MX   3600   10   mail.d2.com.". On d2.com I set an A record "mail   A   3600   10.10.10.1", where 10.10.10.1 is the IP to the mailserver.

It didn't work, emails sent to someone@d1.com disappeared. So then I tried this:

- On d1.com I set a MX record "@   MX   3600   10   mail" and an A record "mail   A   3600   10.10.10.1", where 10.10.10.1 is the IP to the mailserver at d2.com.

This didn't work either, again emails sent to someone@d1.com disappeared. 
Something tells me that I somehow have to tell d2.com to accept mails addressed to anyone@d1.com, since d2.com probably expects mails to be on the format someone@d2.com. Is this "accepting" something I can configure using DNS? Or how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your on the right track with your first DNS changes, however, as you note towards then end of your question, you must configure the Mail Server at d2.com to accept mail from d1.com - this is something to be configured in the mail server and not in DNS.